# Can twistd do an automatic server reset the same way as django?

Tags: python, django, twisted

One of the things I really like about django is the way the server automatically resets when you edit the project.  I've recently started doing some development in twisted/cyclone.

Is there a similar way to make twistd reset automatically when a program file is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) - it enables monitoring filesystem events, such as file modification. There are also python bindings: [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/)
There are many tutorials there, my suggestion is that you implement a wrapper that starts twisted monitors you source path. When a file modification occurs you restart twisted.

Answer (score 1):

I use my own [Pyquitter](https://github.com/ludios/Pyquitter), which polls the source files for every module that the process has imported.  Check out the 'Sample use' in the README, which covers how to use it with Twisted.